# viewChildren with directive

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-directive, viewchild

I want to add a directive and use viewChildren for identify them:

```
// directive.ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[myOwnDirective]'
})
export class MyOwnDirective {

   constructor() { 
      console.log("hi") //never printed
    }
}

//component html:

<div myOwnDirective>content 1</div>
<div>content 2</div>
<div>content 3</div>
<div myOwnDirective>content 4</div>
<button (click)="printElements()"></button>

//component.ts:
 export class MyOwnComponent implements AfterViewInit{


  @ViewChildren(MyOwnDirective) children: QueryList<MyOwnDirective>;

   constructor() {

   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
   }

   printElements(){
     console.log(this.children) // Empty
   }
```

What I want is get all elements with "myOwnDirective" but I can't find how.

where is my mistake?

Comment: have you added your directive in `app.module` ?

Comment: oh thanks! it was my problem! thank you so much. If you want add it as answer in order to mark it as the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register your directive in `app.module` in order to use in your application.